# php array merge by key value pair

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this which is created by merging arrays of sql results in loop

```
    array(175) {
[0]=> array(2) { ["TIMESTAMP"]=> string(10) "2015-10-09" ["ACR"]=> string(4) "4024" } 
[1]=> array(2) { ["TIMESTAMP"]=> string(10) "2015-10-10" ["ACR"]=> string(4) "4024" }
[2]=> array(2) { ["TIMESTAMP"]=> string(10) "2015-10-11" ["ACR"]=> string(4) "4024" }
[7]=> array(2) { ["TIMESTAMP"]=> string(10) "2015-10-09" ["ATC"]=> string(4) "4182" } 
[8]=> array(2) { ["TIMESTAMP"]=> string(10) "2015-10-10" ["ATC"]=> string(4) "4188" } 
[9]=> array(2) { ["TIMESTAMP"]=> string(10) "2015-10-11" ["ATC"]=> string(4) "4188" } 
[14]=> array(2) { ["TIMESTAMP"]=> string(10) "2015-10-09" ["BEL"]=> string(4) "1155" } 
[15]=> array(2) { ["TIMESTAMP"]=> string(10) "2015-10-10" ["BEL"]=> string(4) "1155" } 
[16]=> array(2) { ["TIMESTAMP"]=> string(10) "2015-10-11" ["BEL"]=> string(4) "1155" } 
}
```

and need to merge it by timestamp value

```
array(175) {
[0]=> array(2) { ["TIMESTAMP"]=> string(10) "2015-10-09" ["ACR"]=> string(4) "4024" ["ATC"]=> string(4) "4182" ["BEL"]=> string(4) "1155" } 
[1]=> array(2) { ["TIMESTAMP"]=> string(10) "2015-10-10" ["ACR"]=> string(4) "4024" ["ATC"]=> string(4) "4188" ["BEL"]=> string(4) "1155" }
[2]=> array(2) { ["TIMESTAMP"]=> string(10) "2015-10-11" ["ACR"]=> string(4) "4024" ["ATC"]=> string(4) "4188" ["BEL"]=> string(4) "1155"}
}
```

the second array is expected output

any idea how? I've tried many ways how group arrays but didnt do what I need.
thanks

Comment: How it should be the expected output, can you write it in your question?

Comment: Is it really necessary to merge separate database resultsets?  If you could retrieve all these records from the database in one (ordered) resultset, the grouping operation becomes a trivial matter of comparing the current timestamp against that of the last seen record...

Comment: yes I need to merge separate db results, as I am building queries in loop with different aliases etc...I tried to do this already in oracle, but I have to put column name as a value and was not able to do that

Comment: It sounds as though your schema violates the [Principle of Orthogonal Design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_orthogonal_design).

Comment: I have created a summary table which contains lot of sum, grouped data, duplicates with different timeframe for history purposes etc and I am querying it for lot of reports...it is not a standard normalized DB table

Answer (score 0):

ok I've finally found this solution

```
$merged = array();
foreach ($result as $item)
{
    $date = $item['TIMESTAMP'];
    if (!isset($merged[$date]))
    {
        $merged[$date] = array();
    }
    $merged[$date] = array_merge($merged[$date], $item);
}
```

then it returns array where  key is timestamp value. As I need these data for morris.js line chart, I had to use shuffle and now I have array which works